# HOw to make this php class work as expected

Tags: php

Can anyone see what i have done incorreclty using this class it should change the word before to after but it just sits there doing nothing.
The second php pgm is the actual classs I am using..

```
<?php

include("parse.inc.php");

$bob = new parseClass();

$tag = "{Before}";
$replacement = "After";
$content = "My animal runs around all over the place and his name is {Before}.";
$bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);
echo $bob;

?>




parse.inc.php (file name)
***************************

<?php
Class parseClass {

    function ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content) {
        $content = str_replace($tag, $replacement, $content);
        return $content;
    }

}

// END Class parseClass
?>
```

Comment: you can't echo Object if it is not string. in your case `echo $bob;` is actually an object. you need to use var_dump  or print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the result of your function in a local variable, and print that.

```
$result = $bob->ReplaceTag($x, $y, $z);
print($result);
```

Comment: Evidently i have something else wrong as none of the above idea work but thanks for the suggestions. And not getting any errors in the error file.

Comment: I am getting this errror and looks like wordfence but i turned it off and still there but does not look like its causing this problem but here it is if any reccognizes as a possible problem with what I am doing.
[17-Jul-2017 06:07:06 UTC] Unable to open /home/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.

Comment: Something has to be wrong with my basic hookup... none of those solutions work.. i even changed the function to this and still no work
    function ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content) {
     echo "$tag<br>";
   return $content;
    }

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you pass the content into class's function
Therefore, you should store the return value into variable first

```
$result = $bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to print the string having be replaced,so you should :

```
$result = $bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);
echo $result;
```

Why are you use echo to print class?If you want to do this,please use "var_dump" or 'print_r' instead;

Answer (score 0):

If the hard requirement is that you want to be able to `echo` the instance of `parseClass`, try this:

```
class parseClass 
{
    private $content;

    public function ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content) 
    {
        $this->content = str_replace($tag, $replacement, $content);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}

$bob = new parseClass();

$tag = "{Before}";
$replacement = "After";
$content = "My animal runs around all over the place and his name is {Before}.";

$bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);

echo $bob;
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: oh thanks localheinz.. i am copying your version to see if it works for me maybe i can see something i have done wrong (typo) or something will let you know shortly..

Comment: ok works great i see where you told me to use the to string conversion but did not know how to implement it so thank yu so very much. works like a doll..

Comment: @TomChambers If it works for you, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace these two lines

```
$bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);

echo $bob;
```

with

```
$content = $bob->ReplaceTag($tag, $replacement, $content);

echo $content;
```